# Unable to get access token from Facebook with Server-Side Authentication

Tags: facebook, token, facebook-access-token

I try to get an access_token like this documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

but it does not work !

I have this error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}
```

In the documentation it says we can use :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

client_id is my app_id 
client_secret is the App secret 
redirect_uri is the url of the website (Site URL in app configuration) (I tried with / and without at the end)

So my url is :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=14588084****&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&client_secret=693ce9538e1f14e0*********&code=AQCVmlM9peMiL8Pv3mdi7c3FifwGLQDECdtN0oGMW4I6cisebeawDdSHP_crQlhsZxHKDOFT6zOrqeaoiL2pkQSkqAvwoPZdw0o1uCoLpUVjchghgfhgfhEXb2XS3UBD7iEc8eZ_YLF0cbVWL5i58sj3Rsr9vVFtfYwfghghgfhgfTkwajGcRp9n-lWWcepxghgIwzMMYLv8e__iDoMDiSNg
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been ages since I last coded a Facebook app. Not sure if this will help:  [Facebook access token and AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782809/facebook-access-token-and-ajax-calls)